# Have an HTML input tag restrict a certain input

Tags: html

How do you make an HTML input tag that does not allow the input of 1. It could for instance type 2131 or 11, just not 1 by itself. I have tried using patternMismatch= "[1]{1}" but the website does not render a message.

Comment: what is the valid range of number for the input?

Comment: Input validation is what you want. You should google it for more details, but here are some useful links HTML input pattern if you used patternMissmatch from firefox web api, that is the state that holds true or false, you should not write regex there. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check the value each time the user inputs something. On input, check if the value is 1, if so clear the input field.

Code:

```
let input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    if (!input.value == "1") return;
    input.value = "";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [input type="number"](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_step.asp) with a step of 1 and a min of 2, like so:

```
<form action="/action_page.php"><label for="points">Points:</label> <input type="number" id="points" name="points" step="1" min="2" /> <input type="submit" /></form>
```